# Is this ChannelFuture listener registration robust?

Tags: java, networking, netty, nio

Below is some code snippet from the book < Netty in Action >.
[image]

I am wondering if the connect action finished after `1` and before `2`, will the `ChannelFutureListener` ever get a chance to be notified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the Netty javadoc, specifically for [addListener](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelFuture.html#addListener(io.netty.util.concurrent.GenericFutureListener)). It states that the listener will be notified immediately if the operation is already complete.

So the answer is yes, it's robust.

Comment: Thanks! Right on target.